# I am stuck with this struct in C++

Tags: c++, struct

I am currently learning "struct" in C++ and stuck at this:

```
#include "iostream"
#define SIZE 100

struct date{
  int day;
  int month;
  int year;
};

typedef struct{
  char *name;
  struct date date_of_birth;
  int score;
} person;

void entry(person *roster){
  person temp;
  std::cout << "Input name: " << '\n';
  gets(temp.name);
  std::cout << "Date of birth: " << '\n';
  std::cin >> temp.date_of_birth.day;
  std::cin >> temp.date_of_birth.month;
  std::cin >> temp.date_of_birth.year;
  std::cout << "Score: " << '\n';
  std::cin >> temp.score;
  *roster = temp;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  person roster[SIZE];
  // number of people in roster:
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    entry(&roster[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The program ended just right after I input the n value. Plz help me with this problem, thank you so much

Comment: Aside from the weird `#include "iostream"` and the `std::cin`, your code is pretty much C.

Comment: OT: `#include "iostream"` should be `#include <iostream>`

Comment: If you are learning C++ from a book or tutorial, I suggest you throw it away and get yourself a [better C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead.  There are a lot of C-isms and bad habits in the code that a good C++ book wont have.

Comment: `char *name;` you never allocated memory to assign to this, instead you should prefer `std::string` in C++

Comment: If you're learning C++, go with C++. Starting with C way bring only bad habit and a deep misunderstanding of the language. It's a very old school approach.

Comment: thank you so much, honestly I am trying to learn C++ with a syllabus C book I got from university...

Comment: Please don't do that. C and C++ are different languages. *Very* different. Find a C++ book using the link posted above. Just because C code happens to run in C++ doesn't mean that that's how you *should* code; it will only cause you immense pain

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Most valid C code is valid C++ code. Most good C code is bad C++ code.

Comment: damn, I still can not solve the problems even when using string. Please show me how, I stuck at this for days

Comment: Don't cross the streams, can be bad, very bad.  If you use `std::cin`, don't use `gets`.  (Don't use `gets`, as it can overflow character arrays.)  Instead, use `std::string` and `std::getline`, e.g. `std::getline(std::cin, my_string);`

Comment: FYI, in C++ you don't need the `typedef` keyword with `struct`s or `class`.

Comment: In C++, pass large things by reference or constant reference if the parameter is not modified.  A large thing is something that won't fit in a processor's register.  A pointer can point to anywhere, including invalid locations.  A reference will exist.

Comment: Prefer to use `std::vector` instead of arrays.  Arrays can overflow.  Arrays can underflow (using less than the declared capacity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `gets(temp.name)` does not allocate memory for the string for you, it expects `temp.name` to already point to allocated storage. However, `temp.name` was never initialized, at best your program will crash trying to read the name, at worst it will seem to work but will overwrite memory that will cause problems later. Even if you provide it with a buffer, `gets()` doesn't know how big your buffer is and will happily write past the end of the buffer it the line it tries to read is long enough.
This is why `gets()` is a deprecated function that has been removed since C11, and my compiler won't even compile your code.

To read in a line, either use the POSIX function [`getline()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), which is not standard C or C++, or use C++'s [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function. However, the latter requires you to read into a `std::string`, not into a `char *`.

Finally, as Thomas Matthews mentioned in the comments, don't mix C++'s I/O functions with C I/O functions, so `std::getline()` is the way to go.